# jQuery addClass only to <td> where the parent <tr> has specific class

Tags: javascript, jquery

so what i try to do is, to add a class to every  element, where the parent  has a specific class.

I tried this:

```
if ($('tr').hasClass('storno')) {
        $('tr > td').addClass('storno');
    }
```

and this is the html example:

```
<table>
  <tr class="storno">
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test2</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

i tried it also with some other code, but at this point, i dont know i can get it right.

Thank you very much in advance

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
$('tr.storno > td').addClass('storno');
```

Answer (score 7):

you need to use the [class selector](http://api.jquery.com/class-selector/) along with [descendent selector](http://api.jquery.com/descendant-selector/) to do this

```
$('tr.storno td').addClass('storno');
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/SGcrj/)

Answer (score 1):

Do this

`$('tr.storno > td').addClass('storno');`

Answer (score 1):

simply use a selector with the specific class when you fetch the  nodes:

```
$('tr.specificParentClass').children('td').addClass('tdClass');
```

Answer (score 1):

Here, try this one

```
$('tr.storno').find('td').addClass('storno');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if ($('tr').hasClass('storno')) {
    $(this).find('td').addClass('storno');
}
```